# Convert dplyr pipeline into SQL string

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I would like to convert a (short) `dplyr` pipeline into a string representation of its equivalent SQL. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
dbplyr::lazy_frame() %>% filter(foo == 'bar')
```

will print out essentially what I'm looking for, namely:

```
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `df`
WHERE (`foo` = 'bar')
```

the problem is that this is merely *printed* out. In particular I don't see how to assign it to a string. I've tried appending `%>% show_query()` but I believe that has the same result (i.e., displaying the query rather conversion to a string). Appending `%>% as.character()` does produce something but it is not SQL (it's a character vector whose first element is `"list(name = \"filter\", x = list(x = list(), vars = character(0)), dots = list(~foo == \"bar\"), args = list())"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `remote_query` to get an `c("sql", "character")` and then convert that to `character`.

```
library(dbplyr)

lazy_frame() %>%
  filter(foo == 'bar') %>%
  remote_query %>%
  as.character
## [1] "SELECT *\nFROM `df`\nWHERE (`foo` = 'bar')"
```

Comment: As of [dbplyr 2.3.0](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/01/dbplyr-2-3-0/) this needs the columns listed in the `lasy-frame`. I.e., something like `lazy_frame(foo = 0)`. It would be nice if there was a way to avoid this, but I think there may not be.

Answer (score 4):

You can capture the output:

```
library(dplyr)
x<-capture.output(dbplyr::lazy_frame() %>% filter(foo == 'bar'))
x
[1] "<SQL>"                 "SELECT *"              "FROM `df`"             "WHERE (`foo` = 'bar')"
```

or

```
dbplyr::lazy_frame() %>% filter(foo == 'bar')%>%capture.output
```

Comment: Thank you -- that does answer my question. I am going to wait to see if someone comes up with a `dplyr`/`dbplyr` function that converts it directly to a string (which after all must be possible in some way). If no one does, then I'll accept this.